# How to find every options of specific word in text

Tags: c#, string

I am beginner and I am trying to every word, which contains "srv" word in text.
Here is example

```
Hello, this is test TEST-SRVCole
```

and I want print `TEST-SRVCole`

How to do it the most effective way?

This is what I have:

```
 var test = text.Where(x => x.ToString().ToLower().Contains("srv")).ToArray();
            foreach (var item in test)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
```

But it does not nothing.

Comment: Split on the space first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
var test = text.Where(x => x.ToString().ToLower().Contains("srv")).ToArray();
```

does nothing, because you literally iterate over *characters*.

A simple starting point is (a) splitting the string to words, (b) analyzing each of them. Let's assume a word boundary is just a space:

```
var parts = text.Split(' ');
foreach (var item in parts.Where(part => part.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("srv")))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

In reality, the texts you will be processing will, most likely, have other characters as word boundaries, such as punctuation.